# Chrome created unknown css style snippet by itself?

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, dom

I've created a micro page with absolutely no external references, even without any  `favicon.ico`.
Instead I'm using base64 inline images.
The only CSS I'm using is inline of a `<div>` element.
The following code is not part of my source, so I don't know where it becomes generated.

**Where and how does the following code come from?

What is it's meaning? What consequences does it have?**

[image: From Google Dev Console]

Fulltext for copy&paste:

`<style type="text/css" style="display: none !important;">object:not([type]),object[classid$=":D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"],object[classid$=":d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"],object[codebase*="swflash.cab"],object[data*=".swf"],embed[type="application/x-shockwave-flash"],embed[src*=".swf"],object[type="application/x-shockwave-flash"],object[src*=".swf"],object[codetype="application/x-shockwave-flash"],iframe[type="application/x-shockwave-flash"],object[classid$=":166B1BCA-3F9C-11CF-8075-444553540000"],object[codebase*="sw.cab"],object[data*=".dcr"],embed[type="application/x-director"],embed[src*=".dcr"],object[type="application/x-director"],object[src*=".dcr"],object[classid$=":15B782AF-55D8-11D1-B477-006097098764"],object[codebase*="awswaxf.cab"],object[data*=".aam"],embed[type="application/x-authorware-map"],embed[src*=".aam"],object[type="application/x-authorware-map"],object[src*=".aam"],object[classid*="32C73088-76AE-40F7-AC40-81F62CB2C1DA"],object[type="application/ag-plugin"],object[type="application/x-silverlight"],object[type="application/x-silverlight-2"],object[source*=".xaml"],object[sourceelement*="xaml"],embed[type="application/ag-plugin"],embed[source*=".xaml"]{display: none !important;}</style>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two possibilities:

1) Added by a browser plugin or extension.

Try running in Incognito mode with all extensions disabled, and if it's due to a plugin or extension the additional content will go away.

2) Added by the web server that is serving the web page

To see if it's #2, load the HTML file in your browser using a local file:// URL and check if it's still there.

Most likely it's related to an Ad-Blocking type of browser plugin that is setting { display: none !important } CSS attribute for all Flash, Shockwave, Silverlight, etc. content on the page.

Comment: I opened it in Incognito mode and the additional content was gone.